# setValue doesn't work if wrapperElement is display:none

Tags: codemirror

I've created a CodeMirror instance using the `fromTextArea` function. I want to let users hide the editor if they want. I used `getWrapperElement` to get the wrapper, `wrapper.style.display = "none";` to hide the editor, and `wrapper.removeAttribute("style");` to unhide the editor.

The odd thing is that if I use `cm.setValue("hello")` while the wrapper is hidden and then unhide the wrapper, the editor remains blank. If I do `cm.getValue()` in the Chrome console, then it returns "hello". If I do `cm.setValue("hello")` while the editor is visible, it works like normal.

I want to use `setValue()` to load some code in the background while the editor is hidden and then make it visible when the user unhides the editor.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to call `cm.refresh();` after you make the editor visible.